# Appium C# AppiumDriver<AppiumWebElement>.DeviceTime does not work

Tags: c#, appium

How to get current time on real device (android) using selenium C#
I have tried AppiumDriver.DeviceTime
I got error:
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource

Comment: There must be some bug in your code. String x = Driver.DeviceTime; is working just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017

```
        //C# Appium getting time

        using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
        using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;

        namespace YourNameSpace
        {
            [TestClass]
            public class UnitTest1
            {
                //Creating instance for Appium driver
                AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> _driver;


                [TestMethod]
                public void MainScreen()
                {

                  //set the capabilities 
                   (https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md)
                    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    //remember to put here all your DesiredCapabilities

                    _driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

                    String deviceDateX = _driver.DeviceTime; //Geting device date and time.
                    Console.WriteLine(deviceDateX); //Writing the date and time in console

                    _driver.Quit();



                }
            }
        }
```

I Hope this helps you. :)